# *args returns a list containing only those arguments that are even I tried in two ways but still I am getting the same error

Tags: python, variadic-functions, keyword-argument

*args returns a list containing only those arguments that are even

This is what I tried:

```py
def myfunc(*args):
     for n in args:
         if n%2 == 0:
             return list(args)
             
print(myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
```

error:

```
Error details
Lists differ: [-2, 4] != [-1, -2, 4, 3, 5]

First differing element 0:
-2
-1

Second list contains 3 additional elements.
First extra element 2:
4

- [-2, 4]
+ [-1, -2, 4, 3, 5] : This is incorrect
```

I want to understand the error

Comment: You would never get *that* output from *that* code. Are you talking about the output from some sort of automated testing framework? btw your function returns a list of its args if one of them is even, else it returns `None`. You should look into list comprehensions.

Comment: You want to create a new list, put only even elements into it, and return it **after** the loop! Not return a list of all args once you find one even value.

Comment: `return list(args)` This just returns the original arguments, exactly as they are.  You haven't done anything to return **only** the even ones..

Comment: Now I  understood. Thank you for the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with your function. First, when I run your code I do not get that error. I get the list that was inputted. It also looks like you are using a testing framework.
If you want to get a list of args that are even, you can do this efficiently with list comprehension:

```py
>>> args = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> output = [arg for arg in args if arg%2 == 0]
>>> print(output)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

You are also returning the entire list of args if **one** of the elements is even. The function will terminate after the first even element. If you want to do it in a function, return the list after you have iterated through all the elements.

```
>>> def myfunc(*args):
...     result = []
...     for arg in args:
...         if arg%2 == 0:
...             result.append(arg)
...     return result
...
>>> print(myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```